# Can "quinquagenarian" be employed for something else than a person?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

[Many](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quinquagenarian) [dictionaries'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quinquagenarian) [definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quinquagenarian) of "quinquagenarian" suggest this adjective should be used only when referring to a person.

My question is: can it be used for anything else? For example, is it sound to talk about a *quinquagerarian book*?

Comment: A quinquagerarian book wouldn't be very old.

Comment: Define 'sound'. It's probably licensed semantically, but you'd likely either lose marks for non-idiomaticity in an essay, fail to sell many novels in which you used the word, or be ostracised at the pub.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - No matter.  Simply mentioning a book in a pub is apt to get you ostracized anyway.

Comment: Oh gosh, sounds to me I shouldn't commend my "quinquagenarian beers"! At least I don't go to pubs very often;) Thanks a lot for clarifying this to me (and for sparing me some moments of awkwardness...)

Comment: As a beer, it's far more likely to go down well in a pub than a book.

Comment: @HotLicks can you find a pub where people have conversations any more?

Comment: @BoldBen - Let me set down my iPhone a sec and I'll check here.

Comment: I think most people would be happy using anygenarian for any living thing they might recognise as having a birthday, so including for instance, dogs and trees…